# What is the purpose of a double-pipe in an object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, types

I've come across some samples for a React DND and within one of them was the following code:

```
export type Author = {|
  id: string,
  name: string,
  avatarUrl: string,
  url: string,
|}
```

There are several export types like this with the double pipe `{|...|}` in object brackets, and, despite my research, I can't find anything that explains what it does. I assume it's due to there being multiple Authors that are combined into the final object (re: the following code) and the double-pipes prevent some sort of conflict.

```
const princess: Author = {
  id: '4',
  name: 'Princess bubblegum',
  url: '',
  avatarUrl: '',
};

export const authors: Author[] = [
  jake, BMO, finn, princess,
];
```

Comment: Its not react.Its typescript syntax

Comment: Duplicate of higher-voted [What does flow {| brace pipe |} syntax do?](/q/48393027/4642212).

Comment: Incorrect. This post was created 7 days before the higher-vote duplicate was created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a flowtype exact object type annotation.

https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types

> Sometimes it is useful to disable this behavior and only allow a specific set of properties. For this, Flow supports “exact” object types.

Basically, it will not allow any props outside of the defined ones and should complain if you add, say... `age: 40` to an `Author` object.